# Aviarc screen timeout with file upload

Tags: aviarc

When submitting a screen to process an uploaded file, I've been having trouble with larger files.
Eventually when submitting I get this error:

> An error occurred during the server request:
>   Timeout reached during screen submit background request. Please retry your action

How can I get around the timeout error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to increase the AJAX timeout limit. In Aviarc Admin go to Applications > your app > Variables and add the variable `ajax-timeout-millis` to a time long enough for the file to upload completely (if the variable doesn't exist you can create it).

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file you're trying to upload? It sounds like you need to configure the maximum POST size for the servlet container.

- If using the embedded Jetty, the default POST limit is 10MB - you can configure this in the startup scripts using the HTTP_MAX_POST_SIZE variable.
- If using Tomcat the default POST limit is 2MB, you will need to configure the maxPostSize as described here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html
- Other containers will have their own configuration mechanisms for the max POST size.